# search for value with in column by multiindex and take value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe `df` and I have a second dataframe `df1`. I like to search in `df1` for "SPX" after the value of "correl" an add in `df` the value in the column "correl":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.arrays = [['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
             ["DJ30","SPX","Example","Example","Example","Example"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*np.arrays))),
                  columns=['correl','beta'])

df['correl'] = ''
df['beta'] = ''
df


df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0.95, 0.7, "SPX"]],
                  columns=['correl', 'beta', 'index'])
df1
```

I expect:

```
               correl   whatever
one     DJ30        
        SPX     0.95    
        Example     
two 
        Example     
        Example     
        Example
```

Comment: Can 'SPX' show up under 'two' or other index level zeros labels?

Comment: no, spx will only exist in one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reset_index`, `merge` and `set_index`:

```
df.reset_index().merge(df1, 
                       left_on='level_1', 
                       right_on='index', 
                       suffixes=('_x',''),
                       how='left')\
  .set_index(['level_0','level_1'])
```

Output:

```
                 correl  beta index
level_0 level_1                    
one     DJ30        NaN   NaN   NaN
        SPX        0.95   0.7   SPX
        Example     NaN   NaN   NaN
two     Example     NaN   NaN   NaN
        Example     NaN   NaN   NaN
        Example     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks, but the column "whatever" is removed. all columns in "df" have to remain

Comment: Remove `[df1.columns]` on the end.